# Docker Mount Volume Directory with Install Files

Tags: docker, volumes

I'm working on building a Docker image for Plex Media server. I'm trying to integrate it with Plex Remote Transcoder which requires access to /var/lib/plexmediaserver on the container. This directory is the install directory for Plex.

My problem is that mounting a volume on startup just mounts the host directory to the container.

**How do I mount a populated directory inside the container to my host?**

Answer (score 0):

You [create and mount  data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)

Your Plex Media image declares a volume for /var/lib/plexmediaserver, and its Dockerfile make sure that /var/lib/plexmediaserver is properly filled.

Then any plex remote transcoder container would be run with `--volumes-from <plexMediaServerContainer>`: it would see the content of `/var/lib/plexmediaserver` in its container.